# Having 3 urns, 9 balls(3 blue, 3 red, 3 green) what is the probability we will have in each urn 3 different colors?

Tags: probability

Having 3 urns, we put 9 balls(3 blue, 3 red, 3 green) in those 3 urns. What is the probability we will have in each urn 3 different colors ball?

I thought the number of possible cases is: C of 9 taken by 3 * C of 6 taken by 3 * C of 3 taken 3 = 1680

I just dont know how to find the number of favorable cases. I thought it C of 3 taken by 3 = 1, but I am not sure.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: When we put the nine balls in the three urns, were we trying to put three different colors in each urn? Were we trying to avoid putting three different colors in each urn? Are there some assumptions you are making that you aren't explicitly mentioning?

Comment: consider it as we are blindfolded so there arent any assumptions

Comment: Suggestion: Start by computing the probability that the first urn contains three different colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the 1st urn. It must have one ball of each color. There are three choices of blue ball to go into that urn, then three choices of red, then three of green, so, all told, $3\times3\times3=27$ ways to fill the 1st urn. Similarly, for the 2nd urn, $2\times2\times2=8$, and for the 3rd urn, just $1$. So the total number of favorable cases is $27\times8\times1=216$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine having three $3$-sided dice in each of the colours - the problem is analogous to throwing a $1,2,3$ with each set of dice, which is $\frac{3!}{3^3}=\frac{6}{27}=\frac{2}{9}$, cubed.

Hence the probability is $\frac{8}{729}$ (which equals $\frac{216}{19683}$).